# VBA : How does Merge behave regarding to an Offset'ed Range

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range

The problem in the follwing code is that the `range` being merged is always the `Range("A1:B2")`.

```
'how the range are set (they're dim'ed as Range)

Set Range1 = Sheet1.Range("A1:B2")
Set Range2 = Sheet2.Range("A1:B2")

For i = 1 To col1.Count 'collection with data which will be used further in the code
    If i <> 1 Then 'checking that we're not at the first item
        Sheet1.Rows(range_row + 2 & ":" & range_row + 3).Insert 'range row = 1 at start
        Sheet2.Rows(range_row + 2 & ":" & range_row + 3).Insert
        Sheet1.Rows("61:62").Delete
        Sheet2.Rows("61:62").Delete
        Set Range1 = Range1.Offset(1, 0) 'I've tried with Offset 2 it changes nothing
        Set Range2 = Range1.Offset(1, 0)
        Range1.Merge
        Range2.Merge
        range_row = range_row + 2
    End If
    'other operations not affecting the size of the range
Next i
```

The goal is to merge `Range("A1:B2")` then `Range("A3:B4")` then `Range("A5:B6")` and so on...

What I have :

[image]

Goal

[image]

`Offset` method should shift the range down so that 2 lines can be merged thanks to the `.Merge` method. Apparently after some debuging the problem seems to be that the `Range("A1:B2")` is always merged. But further in my code, I store a value in this Range and it goes in the right cell...

Is it that `Merge` doesn't like an Offset'ed range ? Should I do a different declaration like `As New` for my both Ranges ?

Note that every variable is dim'ed and has the right value, expect that Range.

Comment: I am not able to understand what you try doing...  What `Col1` is? What value `range_row` has? Why do you iterate using `i` variable without using it at all? I think it would be better to try explaining **in words** what you try doing. Or better, edit your question and show two pictures. One showing the existing situation and the other one what you try accomplishing... Do you want merging both columns of range A:B? I mean "A1:B2", "A3:B4", "A5:B6" etc.? If so, based on what to stop iteration? If not, please clearly explain **in words** what you try doing.

Comment: @FaneDuru ```Col1``` is a collection of items just used further in the code. ```Range_row``` starts at 1 like I wrote as a comment in the code.
I want to merge ```Range("A1:B2")``` and ```Range("A3:B4")``` and so on. Like I said right now only the first range (```Range("A1:B2")```) is merged.

Comment: There is a problem with the range after merging. The Offset method result only one cell in column A, because after merge and offset the result for the first loop is A4

Comment: @Blackcat If you mean the merge of the first iteration, I don't know what do you mean because there is no merge at first iteration, the cell is already merged.

Comment: In the second loop the range is a merged range. When you redefine it with offset(1,0) the result is only one cell because of the range is merged.

Comment: @Blackcat I guess I got it but anyway Faneduru gave me an explanation that led me to my mistake. ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, look to the next way of merging two adiacent columns:

```
Sub TesteMergeCells1()
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 1 To 10 Step 2 'use here your collection number of elements instead of 10
    Range("A" & i, "B" & i + 1).merge
  Next i
End Sub

Sub TesteMergeCells2()
  Dim i As Long, rngA As Range
  For i = 1 To 10 Step 2
    Set rngA = Range("A" & i)
    Range(rngA, rngA.Offset(1, 1)).merge
  Next i
End Sub

Sub TesteMergeCells3()
  Dim i As Long, rngAB As Range
  Set rngAB = Range("A1:B2")
  For i = 2 To 6
    rngAB.merge
    Set rngAB = rngAB.Offset(1).Resize(2, 2)
  Next i
End Sub
```

Setting `Set Range1 = Sheet1.Range("A1:B2")` does not make a dynamic range. It is always the same range.

I only tried showing the principle. It should be easy to adapt it to your two sheets, I think. Now I have to leave my office...

Comment: Nice explanation, it works for me now, but it means that even if I redefine the range like this afterwards ```Set Range1 = Range1(1, 0)```, VBA keeps the first definition passed through ```Set``` which is here an hard-coded value. (I'm leaving to, I'll see the answer tomorrow but ty I've resolved my problem.)

Comment: @Etienne NAMUR You need to adapt the range for each iterated row!